# Inconsistency in MS Graph when i am receiving the channels of a team

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am using java in order to implement a notification system in MS Graph. I need to receive every channel which belongs to a specific team. While i was working only with STANDAR channels (public) everything was working as it should. Although when i start to create some private channels i came across a weird case. Sometimes MS Graph returns STANDAR and PRIVATE channels as it should and some other times it returns only STANDAR channels. I done a work around to ask for the channels a lot times but its neither the faster or the best solution as again it's pure luck is i will get every channel.

Here is the code i am currently using to get the channels:

```
private static List<Channel> getTeamChannels(Team team, String accessToken) {
  ensureGraphClient(accessToken);
  IChannelCollectionPage channelPage = graphClient.teams(team.id).channels().buildRequest().get();
  List<Channel> chan = channelPage.getCurrentPage();
  IChannelCollectionPage channelPage2;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     channelPage2 = graphClient.teams(team.id).channels().buildRequest().get();
     if (channelPage2.getCurrentPage().size() > chan.size()) {
        return channelPage2.getCurrentPage();
     } else if (channelPage2.getCurrentPage().size() < chan.size()) {
        return chan;
     }
  }
  return channelPage.getCurrentPage();
}
```

Anyone has come across this issue? Which could be the root of the problem and how I can have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure that the logged on user has necessary scopes/permissions. Also they're part of these one of roles (Global admins/Microsoft Teams service admins). So that they can can access teams that they are not a member of as well. This way you can get the STANDAR, PRIVATE channels without any issue.

Comment: The user I use is the admin of the specific team and has the permissions I saw on Ms graph page. Yet again I don't always get private channels

Comment: I am talking about the global roles of the Team/Org, not just the admin of the given team.

Comment: Hmm ok, I will try it and I will let you know. Thank you sir.

Comment: Sure please go ahead and test it out!!

Comment: it seems that this is the case. When i upgraded my user to "owner" of the whole team i was getting every channel every time ( at least for the 20 times i tried it haha ). Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome @Pantelisy!! Glad that it helped!!